MICRF112: loop vs monopole antenna
I'm designing a PCB that trasmit over 433 MHz with MICRF112. The datasheet says that the device works with monopole or loop antennas. I decided to go with a monopole antenna.
This is the example circuit from the datasheet:

that provides the values of inductors and capacitors of the matching circuit. I understand that they may change depending on the PCB layout but they are at least a starting point.
My question is the following: if I swap the loop antenna with a monopole antenna (still 50 ohm) in the diagram, will all these quantities remain the same? Or should I expect that they may be different to work?

No, the matching network component values will need to be reevaluated if you want maximum efficiency. The datasheet also provides component values to match the IC to a 50 ohm load, and if you use those component values and a nearly ideal monopole and ground plane, you'll be reasonably close. But neither the loop antenna, nor most practical small monopoles that use the PCB as a ground plane, will present a pure 50 ohm load.

I'm aware that they need to be revaluated becausing it is not ideal but what I was asking is if that numbers are still a good starting point if I change the antenna from a loop to a monopole.

@ocirocir - No, the component values are different. Page 8 of the datasheet shows the matching network and the exact values needed for 433/315MHz when loaded with 50 Ohm.

I think we are looking at different datasheets, I'm using the one on the official website: https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MICRF112.pdf (and I think that screenshot already represents the 50 ohm)

@ocirocir - https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/WSG/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/MICRF112-Data-Sheet-DS70005554.pdf. The datasheet I got is from 2024, your version is somewhat older (2013) where the (same) matching network for a 50 Ohm output/load can be found on page 5.

Ok that's strange because the new version doesn't have the circuit in my question. Page 5 (page 8) is the test circuit, and it is also configured for FSK, not sure it is valid for ASK normal application. My figure is for ASK (and still 50 ohm), so which one is correct?

@ocirocir - The newer 2024 datasheet contains of course also the matching network(s) for loop antennas. See page 27 and 31. The matching networks are independent of the chosen modulation, it doesn't matter  if you are using ASK, FSK or any other type of (narrow band) modulation.

Ok, exactly, page 31 is the same of my picture in the question. So I still have two questions: 1) why are they different from the test circuit? 2) Are they usable for monopole antenna?

@ocirocir - The impedance of a loop antenna is anything but 50 Ohm which means it needs a different matching network. For a 50 Ohm load use the matching network(s) on page 8 (v2024) or page 5 (v2013).
